# Creating docker swarm using ansible

Tags: docker, github, ansible, swarm

I am using the following from github to understand how docker swarm works via ansible https://github.com/patocox/ansible-swarm-do

I'm not sure if I can ask this doubt without raising an issue on github, so here I am. I followed the steps in README.md
I also changed my hosts file after finding several possible solutions on github:

```
[admin]
IP_ADDRESS ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
[admin:vars]
ansible_password=vagrant
```

IP_ADDRESS is of the droplet I created on digitalocean. I continue to get this error:

```
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication failed.", "unreachable": true}
```

I am executing the command as given in README.md with appropriate API access token.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to connect with SSH on your host admin with user 'vagrant' and password 'vagrant'.
I don't think it's the default Digital Ocean's credentials (more the vagrant ones).
Launch the playbook with the `-vvvv` option to get more output about authentication problem.

Use the right values for `ansible_ssh_user` and `ansible_ssh_pass`.

You can check them by simply trying to connect directly with SSH:

```
ssh <SSH_USER>@<IP_ADDRESS>
```

BTW, since ansible 2.0 the `ssh_` part is deprecated in `ansible_ssh_user` ([Behavioral Inventory Parameters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters))
You should also use one of `ansible_ssh_pass` or `ansible_password`, not both.